# Star scheme foreign keys allowed on dimension table to dimension table?

Tags: sql

I have an exam tomorrow, it's about data warehousing.
It is about a star scheme...
I know that you always have to have a connection with your dimension table from your fact table. But now I wonder whether it is permissible to have a connection between dimension tables? In some examples this occurs, in some cases it does not...

So normally it's like this:

[image: Starscheme]

But is it allowed to do this:

[image: Starscheme 2]

Comment: That is called a "snowflake" schema.  Whether that is technically a "star schema" might depend on your particular class.

Comment: So my the second picture, that picture is a snowflake schema?

Comment: . . I do not know now if snowflake schemas allow for dimension tables to be shared across dimensions.  I certainly have used such structures -- I can't really imagine how you would efficiently represent something like "product created in country X" along will "sale made in country Y".

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question, I would judge that it is not legitimate to add the connection of the second link. The primary reason being that in a star schema connection are exclusively from fact table(s) to dimension tables.

If you wish to represent this relationship while keeping the star-schema, you have to option to add a table where the two attributes are joined (assuming a 1..* - 1..* cardinality.